# What is the relation between the construction of Reshetikhin-Turaev and Witten's paper?

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, quantum-groups

I have read that the papers of Reshetikhin and Turaev provide a mathematically rigorous framework for the ideas contained in Witten's paper "Quantum field theory and the Jones polynomial".

Can someone explain to me (or point out references) what is the relation between these constructions? I understand that [RT] provide a way to build TQFTs from modular categories, but I don't have a clear view of the bigger picture.